# Is there a way to delete directories in Target Server using TeamCity before build?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment

I have checked the option in TeamCity which says "Clean all files in the checkout directory before the build". But it doesnt seem to delete the folder on the server before it builds and deploys the code. There are always stray files which are no longer needed. Is there any better process / Can we achieve by adding extra command line parameters to Build Step to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting specific folder as the Build Checkout Directory (instead of using default one). You can set this in your VCS Settings page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to select the option the to clean directories before checkout for every run. Otherwise you wil still be left with the issue of stray files